# Not able to run Unit test case using Jersey Test Framework

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jersey

I've just started writing unit test cases JerseyTest framework. I've followed this example

http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/rest-assured-vs-jersey-test-framework-testing-your-restful-web-services/comment-page-1/#comment-4791,

I'm able to run the service to get the JSON data. But when I run the unit test using JUnit,  I'm facing the following issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:408)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:273)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:165)
at com.hascode.tutorial.rest.UserServiceTestUsingJerseyTestFramework.<init>(UserServiceTestUsingJerseyTestFramework.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:406)
    ... 25 more

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add a module containing a Jersey test container implementation, e.g. `jersey-test-framework-grizzly2`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can find more info in the chapter dedicated to [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/test-framework.html).